# Prevent closing of workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

There is `ABC.xls` file which has the macro. Now, the macro has a sub which is getting called when I press `Ctrl + M`. 
This sub will open a Open File Dialog where the user can choose a `CSV` file. So basically, this macro is used for processing and saving `CSV` file.
Below is the code which gets called on pressing `Ctrl + M`.

```
Sub runProperChangeSubroutine()             ' Assigned to shortcut key CTRL + M.
    file_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name         ' Gets the file name.
    Application.Run file_name & "!ChangeSub"
End Sub
```

When the user closes the workbook, I have to test for a condition like each row in the `CSV` has a termination string. If that termination string is not
present, I should popup a message box to the user and prevent the closing of workbook.
So I did the following...

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim improperRowNumber As Integer
    Dim BlnEventState As Boolean
    improperRowNumber = returnImproperRow()

    BlnEventState = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If improperRowNumber <> -1 Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "The row number " & improperRowNumber & " is not ending with '@/#'. Please correct the row before closing."
    Else
        Call saveCSV
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = BlnEventState
End Sub
```

On clicking of the close (X mark on top right corner, closing of workboox. I am not closing the excel.) button, I am able to see the message box but the workboox closes. I want user to make some edit if the row is not properly ended.
Please suggest.

Edited:
As the above code is not working, I used `ThisWorkbook.Saved = False` after the message box as shown below...

```
If improperRowNumber <> -1 Then
    MsgBox "The row number " & improperRowNumber & " is not ending with '@/#'. Please correct the row before closing."
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = False
    Cancel = False
Else
```

Now it displays the "`Do you want to save the changes....`" message box. If I click on `Cancel` button on message box, the workbook is not closed.

Is there a way to customize the message box text or buttons or hide this `Save` message box?

Comment: You should not  be able to close the workbook with Cancel = True in Workbook_BeforeClose. Maybe you have something like EnableEvents = False in soubroutine improperRowNumber?

Comment: No, the EnableEvents statement is not present in the improperRowNumber sub. Is there any other possibelities?

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec with application events disabled, the msgbox wouldn't be showing up... But OP's handler is clearly running.

Comment: FWIW I can't seem to be able to cancel the close either. Thank you, now I'll be spending hours researching wtf is going on lol

Comment: Your process is not very clear. What do you do with the CSV file when the user selects it? (Open it like a workbook? Import its data to ABC.xls? Something else?) In which file did you put your `Workbook_BeforeClose` code? Which file are trying to prevent from closing? -- I'm not trying to be pedantic, but those are important details that will help people provide useful answers and address any incorrect assumptions you've made.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here but since you succesfully can detect a line without a proper ending ('@/#'), why cannot your code add that by itself to that very line?

Comment: @peakpeak: Ha ha ha, sometimes I will be over smart and waste too much amount of time and you see points as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you must monitor the closing of workbooks other than the one containing the macros, you can intercept application-level events from your macro-enabled workbook as follows:

Add (or adapt) this code behind ThisWorkbook:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_CloseHelper As CloseHelper

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set m_CloseHelper = New CloseHelper
End Sub
```

Add a new Class Module named CloseHelper:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_App As Excel.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_App = Excel.Application
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_App = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub m_App_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Logic goes here, e.g. the code below will prevent the user from closing
    'any workbook other than this one, for as long as this workbook is open.
    If Not Wb Is ThisWorkbook Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Hello from m_App_WorkbookBeforeClose"
    End If
End Sub
```

The important keyword is WithEvents, and the principle is that events raised by the Excel application can now be coded against within the CloseHelper class.

You'll find a more in-depth article here: [Application Events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the X-button in the top right quits the Excel application. You shouldn't expect the workbook to remain open when the application is closed. You could write an application-event procedure preventing Excel from quitting, but the better way might be to simply get rid of the bad habit of using that button. Find another way to close the workbook.

Comment: Top right corner, I meant closing the workbook, i am not closing the excel. I will edit the post. Thanks.

Comment: Frankly, I doubt that the workbook is being closed with File -> Close, the MsgBox comes up, and the workbook is still closed. If it really is closed under such circumstances the action should originate from some other code running unexpectedly. However, if you are truly faced with a malfunction of the Excel application, or if you can't control how people close the workbook, the next thing to try is to utilise an application event (now you are using a Workbook event) to carry out the same test you already have. Therefore I believe my answer is still valid.

Comment: I think it should not matter if you are closing the workbook or closing the excel. Both the ways the Workbook_BeforeClose gets called.

Comment: It's a matter of sequence. When you quit Excel (1) open workbooks are closed, (2) Closing of your workbook is prevented successfully, (3) Excel can't quit without closing that workbook, (4) Excel decides that it doesn't want to get hung up on the discrepancy between code and user instructions, (5) Excel forces the workbook to close, (6) Excel is unloaded. Moral of the story: don't give conflicting instructions. Learn about programming for application events here:- http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Workbook_BeforeClose event only applies to the workbook in which the code is located. It runs when you try to close the macro workbook and setting its parameter Cancel to TRUE only cancels the closure of the macro workbook when you close Excel. The csv file that is open is a separate workbook and Excel tries to close that separately, generating a separate message about saving the csv file.

To automatically prevent the csv file from being closed, you need to use extensibility programming to add a Workbook_BeforeClose event to the csv file while it is open in Excel. Obviously you can't save the file with the event in place, but you don't need to. The code sitting in the module will run while the workbook is still open preventing closure when your conditions are not met; and a successful save allowed after conditions *are* met will be in the .csv format which will wipe the temporarily added code.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing all your **add-ins** (or run Excel in Safe Mode)?

I'm asking because this problem could be due to the fact that one of your add-ins contains an **Application Level Event** like the one described in Excelosaurus' answer. And it could contain `Application.EnableEvents = False` or even `Cancel = False` and interfere with your code.

EDIT: This would be especially hard to detect with an add-in that is protected since the code would run *after* Workbook_BeforeClose and you won't be able to know what it's doing even if you were debugging line by line using F8.

Comment: If events were disabled, the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event would not run at all.

Comment: The Application Level Event runs **after** the Workbook Level Event, so the Workbook Level Event will always run even if the one at the application level disables events.

Comment: (As long as events were enabled before the X button was pressed of course.)

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that since OP indicated some code within the workbook event is running, `Application.EnableEvents = False` can't be the source of the trouble - it would stop everything. It would be weird, but in theory an add-in could be setting `Cancel = False`.

Comment: You could also have this:
`Application.EnableEvents = False`
`Wb.Close SaveChanges:=False`
`Application.EnableEvents = True`
Which would stop Workbook_BeforeClose from running the *second* time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in the workbook macro

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Workbooks.Open Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
End Sub
```

As you can see it basically saves and open the workbook when it close